# Any SSD folks living near Belarus? There's a fortress there that needs to be recorded.

Tags: impulse-response, field-recording, historical, collaboration

Just watched a [video](http://rt.com/Top_News/2010-05-03/brest-fortress-losses.html#) about the [Brest fortress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brest_Fortress) which was absolutely fascinating. The history and tragedy that occurred there in 1940 is truly moving. Then I got to thinking about what fabulous sounds may be lurking in this place…

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was in Minsk several years ago. Belarus is not particularly easy to enter (its still a relatively closed country due to the Lukashenko dictatorship). There are a number of such fortress ruins in the area. I have been to some in Tallinn and Riga, but haven't recorded there. In May we documented the amazing acoustic properties of a Seaplane hangar in Tallinn commissioned by the last Czar of Russia. http://maaheli.ee/main/archives/1504

Comment: @jgrzinich -- Wow, thanks for sharing that. What an absolutely amazing acoustic that space has! I think Thomas Ankersmit's performance best illustrated it. Are those recordings available? If so, I would love high-rez copies. 

Comment: actually we just made a deal, that the Ankersmit recording will be released as a podcast, not sure when but I'll let you know.